# Android Google Drive API - Previously taken backup doesn't work with the upgraded SDK

Tags: android, google-drive-api, backup, google-drive-android-api

I have an app using the Google Drive Android API for backup/restore feature. I am using [App Folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder#what_is_the_app_folder) to store the backup files. As of the `targetSdkVersion 26`, the below code has been deprecated.

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
```

I have upgraded a Google Drive SDK, followed the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) & the [github project](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples).

Now, Backup/restore works with the upgraded SDK. Backup/Resstore works with the older SDK. But unable to restore the previously taken backup (using older SDK) with the upgraded SDK.

I have verified the backup file name as well as meta-data. I have also tried removing the App folder from the Google drive settings. But nothing works.

How should I make my users restore the previously taken backup with the upgraded SDK?